# "Screenshot" in italiano

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrase-request

Uno "screenshot" si rende in spagnolo come "captura de pantalla" o, in modo più colloquiale, come "pantallazo".

Mi chiedo se esista qualche espressione italiana più o meno usuale per tradurre "screenshot".

Ho pensato che potrebbe essere "cattura di schermo". Tuttavia, una ricerca su Google di questa locuzione dà alcune occorrenze, ma non molte e di siti che mi sembrano poco affidabili.

Comment: In informatica è comune usare termini inglesi (un po' per pigrizia, un po' per convenzione); l'equivalente italiano dovrebbe essere _schermata catturata_ o _cattura dello schermo_ .Oppure anche semplicemente _schermata_ (sottointendendo che è appunto un immagine che rappresenta il contenuto a video);  anche _cattura_ (anche in questo caso, si sottointende che si parla dello schermo). Troverei accettabile anche _foto dello schermo_ anche se mi sa di meno "tecnico".

Comment: Forse questo da Wikipedia ti puo essere utile: ***Il termine inglese screenshot*** (da screen che significa "schermo" e shot invece "scatto fotografico"), ***in italiano fermo-immagine, schermata,  immagine dello schermo o cattura dello schermo***, indica ciò che viene visualizzato in un determinato istante sullo schermo di un monitor, di un televisore o di un qualunque dispositivo video.

***Il primo uso noto del termine screenshot risale al 1983 ed è attribuito al giornalista Bill Kunkel.***

Comment: @Hachi, ti stavo rispondendo nei commenti, ma è sparito tutto... Grazie per il nuovo contributo. So che lo sai, ma sottolineerei, a scanso di malintesi, che lì ci si riferisce al primo uso in inglese (Kunkel non scriveva in italiano).

Comment: A volte si usa anche "videata" (=schermata); secondo me entrambe le parole indicano il contenuto del video in un dato momento, non una copia. Però se si dice a un utente "mandami la videata" è chiaro che s'intende "mandami una copia del contenuto dello schermo".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In italiano la maggior parte dei sistemi operativi traduce il termine "Screenshot" con "Schermata". Altre traduzioni che si sentono spesso (o che almeno io ho sentito dire molte volte) sono "Cattura dello schermo" o "Foto allo schermo"; nonostante ci siano queste alternative l'espressione più utilizzata è comunque proprio "Screenshot".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie per la risposta!

Comment: Basandomi nel suggerimento della tua risposta, ho ricercato su Google "schermata" "strumento" e ho trovato queste immagini: https://blog.dangerx82.it/images/articoli/ubuntu/screenshot/strumento-screenshot.png, https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2015/01/strumento-di-cattura.jpg. Quindi Ubuntu usa "schermata" e invece su Windows è "strumento di cattura"?

Comment: @Charo stai parlando dello strumento di cattura dello schermo; sì, su Windows si chiama così. Sul MAC si chiama "Scatta istantanea schermo"

Comment: È esattamente come dice @RiccardoDeContardi

Comment: Grazie a te @Charo

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - “strumento di cattura” dev’essere una traduzione maldestra di qualcuno. Fa venire  in mente un dispositivo per la caccia piuttosto che una funzione  digitale.

Comment: @Hachi sto andando a memoria, più avanti controllo

Comment: @Hachi: Si vede nell'immagine di uno dei link che ho messo nel mio commento, però.

Comment: @Charo - si l’ho visto, mi chiedevo chi avesse potuto fare una traduzione del genere.

Comment: Referring to phone screenshots, some people say "screen" (pronounced in the Italian way). ex. "Mandami lo screen". Apple computers call a screenshot a "schermata".